# The screen dims but the dialog doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-listfragment

I have created a list inside a **Fragment** using an Adapter. I want to display a different dialog for each one of the items in the list when it is clicked. I have added the listener to the list items and written the code for the dialog to appear for one of the items (the second one). However, when I click that item, **the phone screen dims but the dialog doesn't show up**. I have added the relevant code below. I have searched a lot about this problem on the internet and have tried a lot of different things myself but nothing seems to work.
Everything else in the app works fine.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

DialogFragment Class:

```
public class GenreDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.setTitle(R.string.title_genre_dialog);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // on success
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
}
```

Parent Fragment Class in which I want the dialog to appear:

```
public class FragmentAddWatchedMovie extends ListFragment{
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SetListAdapter();
    SetClickListener();

}
private void SetClickListener() {
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:{
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    GenreDialogFragment fragment = new GenreDialogFragment();
                    fragment.setTargetFragment(FragmentAddWatchedMovie.this,0);
                    fragment.show(manager, "GenreDialog_Fragment");
                    break;

                }
                case 1:{

                }
                case 2:{

                }
                case 3:{

                }
                case 4:{

                }
                case 5:{

                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Try to move "AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();" right above the return line please.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the following line: "`AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();`" right above the return line in the `Dialog` class.

That didn't work for you because you created the Dialog before setting the preferences on the builder :)

Comment: I had a similar error. I was setting all the dialog options (title, message, buttons) in MyDialog.onCreate(). Something changed in new Android version, so dialog wasn't shown. I moved almost all the code in constructor of MyDialog() and everything worked out.